# Remove same elements from list with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to remove duplicate value remain one with LINQ

Example:

```
{2,4,5,2,6,2,8,6,9}
```

Result:

```
{4,5,2,8,6,9}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your list is like:

```
var x = new List<int> {2,4,5,2,6,2,8,6,9};
```

You can distinct it:

```
var y = x.Distinct();
```

If you need the result as a `List<T>` rather than an enumerable, ToList() it (but if all you're doing is eg looping over it, don't bother: `foreach(var unique in x.Distinct())`)